# Remove hashtag from anchor link in index.html scroll page

Tags: html, web, url, hashtag

I'm very new to coding, around 8 months. I made a website from some template and changed it, all is well but I am not able to remove the # from the URL address when scrolling to the anchor on the same page which is index.html.

I've searched a lot but couldn't find anything, will post my code down and please if it's possible to provide a script without the dollar signs $ because they are still confusing me.

```
<header class="site-header">
    <nav class="nav-primary">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>

            <li><a href="#about" >About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio" >Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog" >Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I'm getting this hashtag in the link

https://www.dxbdjs.info/#index.html/DXBDJSERVICES

Answer (score 0):

You could use java script to scroll to different areas. hope that helps, its just a few lines of code.

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

then makes buttons and style them as a link

```
button {
border: none;
background: transparent;
color: #0000ff;
text-decoration: underline;
}

button:hover {
color: #0000ff;
}

button:active {
color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: also do note, the "$" is mainly used in a js library called JQuery. the "$" sign is a selector, u cn use is in a way somethign like this
$(".navbar")(function)(function params)